# Comparing date array to current date in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of dates in an angular controller and I am trying to compare those dates to today's current date, and if they are in the past, then they should be given the class 'red'. however, my code is currently broken. not sure what i am doing wrong, any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

please see plunker link below:
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMyqtJMi8i9uNYnN3yit?p=info)

```
//app.js

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var artists=[
    {eventDate:"2017-01-09"},
    {eventDate:"2016-01-09"},
    {eventDate:"2015-01-09"},
    {eventDate:"2014-01-09"},
    {eventDate:"2013-01-09"},
    ];

  var currentdate = new Date();

  var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#thing' ) );
  for (i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
    if (currentdate > artists[i][0]) {
      myEl.addClass('red');
    }
  }

  $scope.currentdate = currentdate;
  $scope.myEl = myEl;
  $scope.artists = artists;

});

//css
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}

//index.html
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
     <p id="thing" class="blue">event Date {{artist.eventDate | date}}</p>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and use `moment` to compare dates in js: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Answer (score -1):

you can edit your html with ng-class directive:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
      <p id="thing" ng-class="{'red': currentDate > artist.eventDate, 'blue': currentDate <= artist.eventDate}">
        event Date {{artist.eventDate | date}}</p>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: i attempted this to no avail